# artifactory - error could not update recurrent task

Tags: containers, artifactory

We have deployed artifactory on premise with a docker container on separate machine. We have seen that sometimes our build on jenkins fails due to "Could not transfer artifact from/to central : transfer failed for, status: 503 Service Unavailable" which led us to logs of artifactory itself.

From docker container logs, it looks like it is due to task running related to garbage cleaner not completed thus giving error that database is locked. these tasks are

- `deletedVersionsGarbageCollectorTask`
- `deleteOrphanVersionMigrationTask`

Logs for docker container from one particular instance is as follows

```
2024-01-11T13:03:04.025Z [37m[jffe ][39m [34m[INFO ][39m [] [frontend-service.log] [main                ] - fetchAndUpdateAllConfigurations - running fetch and update all configurations
2024-01-11T13:03:20.646Z [34;1m[jfmd ][0m [34m[INFO ][0m [                ] [database_bearer.go:403        ] [main                ] [] - Slow statement detected (5.004991346s) - UPDATE md_servers SET last_heartbeat = ? WHERE id = ? [database]
2024-01-11T13:03:20.646Z [34;1m[jfmd ][0m [34m[INFO ][0m [                ] [server_bearer.go:143          ] [main                ] [] - RETRY: fail to update heartbeat for server in the database [ServerInit]
2024-01-11T13:03:21.676Z [34;1m[jfmd ][0m [31m[WARN ][0m [                ] [readiness_service.go:53       ] [main                ] [] - Service is unavailable, readiness check failed [readiness]
2024-01-11T13:03:21.677Z [36m[jfrou][0m [31;1m[ERROR][0m [6091653573b4e28b] [healthcheck.go:71             ] [main                ] [] - Checking health of service 'jfmd_01fg443hnw6bby1qs5jsjsf5kk-e0afa00755ae' using URL 'http://localhost:8086/api/v1/system/readiness' returned unexpected response status: 503
2024-01-11T13:03:25.656Z [34;1m[jfmd ][0m [34m[INFO ][0m [                ] [database_bearer.go:403        ] [main                ] [] - Slow statement detected (5.006730151s) - UPDATE md_servers SET last_heartbeat = ? WHERE id = ? [database]
2024-01-11T13:03:25.657Z [34;1m[jfmd ][0m [34m[INFO ][0m [                ] [server_bearer.go:143          ] [main                ] [] - RETRY: fail to update heartbeat for server in the database [ServerInit]
2024-01-11T13:03:25.915Z [36m[jfrou][0m [31;1m[ERROR][0m [6b537f6ea0252f6f] [healthcheck.go:71             ] [main                ] [] - Checking health of service 'jfmd_01fg443hnw6bby1qs5jsjsf5kk-e0afa00755ae' using URL 'http://localhost:8086/api/v1/system/readiness' returned unexpected response status: 503
2024-01-11T13:03:25.916Z [36m[jfrou][0m [31m[WARN ][0m [6b537f6ea0252f6f] [local_topology.go:274         ] [main                ] [] - Readiness test failed with the following error: "required node services are missing or unhealthy"
2024-01-11T13:03:30.916Z [36m[jfrou][0m [31;1m[ERROR][0m [4e1bd8943b702119] [healthcheck.go:71             ] [main                ] [] - Checking health of service 'jfmd_01fg443hnw6bby1qs5jsjsf5kk-e0afa00755ae' using URL 'http://localhost:8086/api/v1/system/readiness' returned unexpected response status: 503
2024-01-11T13:03:30.916Z [36m[jfrou][0m [31m[WARN ][0m [4e1bd8943b702119] [local_topology.go:274         ] [main                ] [] - Readiness test failed with the following error: "required node services are missing or unhealthy"
2024-01-11T13:03:34.025Z [37m[jffe ][39m [34m[INFO ][39m [] [frontend-service.log] [main                ] - fetchAndUpdateAllConfigurations - running fetch and update all configurations
2024-01-11T13:03:35.918Z [36m[jfrou][0m [31m[WARN ][0m [2d13737052e69b32] [local_topology.go:274         ] [main                ] [] - Readiness test failed with the following error: "required node services are missing or unhealthy"
2024-01-11T13:03:40.923Z [1;33m[jfac ][0;39m [34m[INFO ][0;39m [                ] [CertificateFileHandlerBase:134] [ault-executor-153130] - Loading root certificate from database.
2024-01-11T13:03:40.925Z [1;33m[jfac ][0;39m [34m[INFO ][0;39m [                ] [.s.b.AccessProjectBootstrap:88] [jf-common-pool-346  ] - Finished initializing Projects permissions in 2.69 millis
2024-01-11T13:03:41.025Z [1;33m[jfac ][0;39m [34m[INFO ][0;39m [                ] [CertificateFileHandlerBase:160] [ault-executor-153130] - [ACCESS BOOTSTRAP] Saved new root certificate at: /opt/jfrog/artifactory/var/etc/access/keys/root.crt
2024-01-11T13:03:41.025Z [1;33m[jfac ][0;39m [34m[INFO ][0;39m [                ] [CertificateFileHandlerBase:143] [ault-executor-153130] - Finished loading root certificate from database.
2024-01-11T13:03:41.026Z [1;33m[jfac ][0;39m [34m[INFO ][0;39m [                ] [CertificateFileHandlerBase:134] [ault-executor-153130] - Loading ca certificate from database.
2024-01-11T13:03:41.126Z [1;33m[jfac ][0;39m [34m[INFO ][0;39m [                ] [CertificateFileHandlerBase:160] [ault-executor-153130] - [ACCESS BOOTSTRAP] Saved new ca certificate at: /opt/jfrog/artifactory/var/etc/access/keys/ca.crt
2024-01-11T13:03:41.127Z [1;33m[jfac ][0;39m [34m[INFO ][0;39m [                ] [CertificateFileHandlerBase:143] [ault-executor-153130] - Finished loading ca certificate from database.
2024-01-11T13:03:41.129Z [1;33m[jfac ][0;39m [34m[INFO ][0;39m [                ] [alConfigurationServiceBase:188] [ault-executor-153130] - Loading configuration from db finished successfully
2024-01-11T13:03:41.732Z [[35[jfob ][0m [34m[INFO ][0m [756c83ada069202b] [shipping_service.go:218       ] [main                ] [] - Adoption.config is disabled in Platform Configuration [shipping_service]
2024-01-11T13:03:58.576Z [1;33m[jfac ][0;39m [34m[INFO ][0;39m [46a0084c83902f0c] [.s.s.r.StaleTokenCleanupJob:62] [jf-access-task6     ] - Starting Access job to remove stale nodes and join-admin-tokens on server: e0afa00755ae
2024-01-11T13:04:04.026Z [37m[jffe ][39m [34m[INFO ][39m [] [frontend-service.log] [main                ] - fetchAndUpdateAllConfigurations - running fetch and update all configurations
2024-01-11T13:04:34.028Z [37m[jffe ][39m [34m[INFO ][39m [] [frontend-service.log] [main                ] - fetchAndUpdateAllConfigurations - running fetch and update all configurations
2024-01-11T13:04:41.732Z [[35[jfob ][0m [34m[INFO ][0m [756c83ada069202b] [shipping_service.go:218       ] [main                ] [] - Adoption.config is disabled in Platform Configuration [shipping_service]
2024-01-11T13:04:45.026Z [1;32m[jfrt ][0;39m [31m[WARN ][0;39m [                ] [j.a.c.g.GrpcStreamObserver:112] [efault-executor-8887] - Access Projects Client 1 - target server is unavailable or connection was shutdown
2024-01-11T13:04:45.027Z [1;32m[jfrt ][0;39m [31m[WARN ][0;39m [                ] [j.a.c.g.GrpcStreamObserver:112] [efault-executor-8881] - Access Platform Config Client 1 - target server is unavailable or connection was shutdown
2024-01-11T13:04:45.028Z [1;32m[jfrt ][0;39m [31m[WARN ][0;39m [                ] [j.a.c.g.GrpcStreamObserver:112] [efault-executor-8891] - Access License Client 1 - target server is unavailable or connection was shutdown
2024-01-11T13:04:45.028Z [1;32m[jfrt ][0;39m [31m[WARN ][0;39m [                ] [j.a.c.g.GrpcStreamObserver:112] [efault-executor-8890] - Access Permission Client 1 - target server is unavailable or connection was shutdown
2024-01-11T13:04:47.104Z [1;32m[jfrt ][0;39m [34m[INFO ][0;39m [                ] [ffectedConfigStreamObserver:40] [scribe ccsslcnsclnt1] - publishing full invalidation and attempting to resubscribe to affected configuration changes
2024-01-11T13:04:47.133Z [1;32m[jfrt ][0;39m [34m[INFO ][0;39m [                ] [ffectedConfigStreamObserver:40] [ ccsspltfrmcnfgclnt1] - publishing full invalidation and attempting to resubscribe to affected configuration changes
2024-01-11T13:04:48.765Z [1;32m[jfrt ][0;39m [34m[INFO ][0;39m [                ] [ectedEntitiesStreamObserver:34] [ribe ccssprmssnclnt1] - publishing full invalidation and attempting to resubscribe to affected permissions changes
2024-01-11T13:05:04.029Z [37m[jffe ][39m [34m[INFO ][39m [] [frontend-service.log] [main                ] - fetchAndUpdateAllConfigurations - running fetch and update all configurations
2024-01-11T13:05:15.648Z [34;1m[jfmd ][0m [34m[INFO ][0m [                ] [database_bearer.go:403        ] [main                ] [] - Slow statement detected (5.007234096s) - UPDATE md_servers SET last_heartbeat = ? WHERE id = ? [database]
2024-01-11T13:05:15.648Z [34;1m[jfmd ][0m [34m[INFO ][0m [                ] [server_bearer.go:143          ] [main                ] [] - RETRY: fail to update heartbeat for server in the database [ServerInit]
2024-01-11T13:05:25.646Z [34;1m[jfmd ][0m [34m[INFO ][0m [                ] [database_bearer.go:403        ] [main                ] [] - Slow statement detected (5.005158323s) - UPDATE md_servers SET last_heartbeat = ? WHERE id = ? [database]
2024-01-11T13:05:25.646Z [34;1m[jfmd ][0m [34m[INFO ][0m [                ] [server_bearer.go:143          ] [main                ] [] - RETRY: fail to update heartbeat for server in the database [ServerInit]
2024-01-11T13:05:30.655Z [34;1m[jfmd ][0m [34m[INFO ][0m [                ] [database_bearer.go:403        ] [main                ] [] - Slow statement detected (5.0053729s) - UPDATE md_servers SET last_heartbeat = ? WHERE id = ? [database]
2024-01-11T13:05:30.656Z [34;1m[jfmd ][0m [34m[INFO ][0m [                ] [server_bearer.go:143          ] [main                ] [] - RETRY: fail to update heartbeat for server in the database [ServerInit]
2024-01-11T13:05:34.029Z [37m[jffe ][39m [34m[INFO ][39m [] [frontend-service.log] [main                ] - fetchAndUpdateAllConfigurations - running fetch and update all configurations
2024-01-11T13:05:35.664Z [34;1m[jfmd ][0m [34m[INFO ][0m [                ] [database_bearer.go:403        ] [main                ] [] - Slow statement detected (5.004886732s) - UPDATE md_servers SET last_heartbeat = ? WHERE id = ? [database]
2024-01-11T13:05:35.664Z [34;1m[jfmd ][0m [34m[INFO ][0m [                ] [server_bearer.go:143          ] [main                ] [] - RETRY: fail to update heartbeat for server in the database [ServerInit]
2024-01-11T13:05:36.684Z [34;1m[jfmd ][0m [31m[WARN ][0m [                ] [readiness_service.go:53       ] [main                ] [] - Service is unavailable, readiness check failed [readiness]
2024-01-11T13:05:36.685Z [36m[jfrou][0m [31;1m[ERROR][0m [2d5414d3229f2b36] [healthcheck.go:71             ] [main                ] [] - Checking health of service 'jfmd_01fg443hnw6bby1qs5jsjsf5kk-e0afa00755ae' using URL 'http://localhost:8086/api/v1/system/readiness' returned unexpected response status: 503
2024-01-11T13:05:40.931Z [36m[jfrou][0m [31;1m[ERROR][0m [47ba8ce2970af65b] [healthcheck.go:71             ] [main                ] [] - Checking health of service 'jfmd_01fg443hnw6bby1qs5jsjsf5kk-e0afa00755ae' using URL 'http://localhost:8086/api/v1/system/readiness' returned unexpected response status: 503
2024-01-11T13:05:40.933Z [36m[jfrou][0m [31m[WARN ][0m [47ba8ce2970af65b] [local_topology.go:274         ] [main                ] [] - Readiness test failed with the following error: "required node services are missing or unhealthy"
2024-01-11T13:05:41.734Z [[35[jfob ][0m [34m[INFO ][0m [756c83ada069202b] [shipping_service.go:218       ] [main                ] [] - Adoption.config is disabled in Platform Configuration [shipping_service]
2024-01-11T13:05:45.933Z [36m[jfrou][0m [31;1m[ERROR][0m [141a2aa86608af29] [healthcheck.go:71             ] [main                ] [] - Checking health of service 'jfmd_01fg443hnw6bby1qs5jsjsf5kk-e0afa00755ae' using URL 'http://localhost:8086/api/v1/system/readiness' returned unexpected response status: 503
2024-01-11T13:05:45.937Z [36m[jfrou][0m [31m[WARN ][0m [141a2aa86608af29] [local_topology.go:274         ] [main                ] [] - Readiness test failed with the following error: "required node services are missing or unhealthy"
2024-01-11T13:05:50.935Z [36m[jfrou][0m [31m[WARN ][0m [450cd5609d07db4d] [local_topology.go:274         ] [main                ] [] - Readiness test failed with the following error: "required node services are missing or unhealthy"
2024-01-11T13:05:55.941Z [1;33m[jfac ][0;39m [34m[INFO ][0;39m [                ] [CertificateFileHandlerBase:134] [ault-executor-153135] - Loading root certificate from database.
2024-01-11T13:05:55.944Z [1;33m[jfac ][0;39m [34m[INFO ][0;39m [                ] [.s.b.AccessProjectBootstrap:88] [jf-common-pool-348  ] - Finished initializing Projects permissions in 2.72 millis
2024-01-11T13:05:56.049Z [1;33m[jfac ][0;39m [34m[INFO ][0;39m [                ] [CertificateFileHandlerBase:160] [ault-executor-153135] - [ACCESS BOOTSTRAP] Saved new root certificate at: /opt/jfrog/artifactory/var/etc/access/keys/root.crt
2024-01-11T13:05:56.050Z [1;33m[jfac ][0;39m [34m[INFO ][0;39m [                ] [CertificateFileHandlerBase:143] [ault-executor-153135] - Finished loading root certificate from database.
2024-01-11T13:05:56.050Z [1;33m[jfac ][0;39m [34m[INFO ][0;39m [                ] [CertificateFileHandlerBase:134] [ault-executor-153135] - Loading ca certificate from database.
2024-01-11T13:05:56.152Z [1;33m[jfac ][0;39m [34m[INFO ][0;39m [                ] [CertificateFileHandlerBase:160] [ault-executor-153135] - [ACCESS BOOTSTRAP] Saved new ca certificate at: /opt/jfrog/artifactory/var/etc/access/keys/ca.crt
2024-01-11T13:05:56.152Z [1;33m[jfac ][0;39m [34m[INFO ][0;39m [                ] [CertificateFileHandlerBase:143] [ault-executor-153135] - Finished loading ca certificate from database.
2024-01-11T13:05:56.154Z [1;33m[jfac ][0;39m [34m[INFO ][0;39m [                ] [alConfigurationServiceBase:188] [ault-executor-153135] - Loading configuration from db finished successfully
2024-01-11T13:06:04.030Z [37m[jffe ][39m [34m[INFO ][39m [] [frontend-service.log] [main                ] - fetchAndUpdateAllConfigurations - running fetch and update all configurations
2024-01-11T13:06:34.032Z [37m[jffe ][39m [34m[INFO ][39m [] [frontend-service.log] [main                ] - fetchAndUpdateAllConfigurations - running fetch and update all configurations
2024-01-11T13:06:41.731Z [[35[jfob ][0m [34m[INFO ][0m [756c83ada069202b] [shipping_service.go:218       ] [main                ] [] - Adoption.config is disabled in Platform Configuration [shipping_service]
```

Logs from metadata-service.log file for that whole day is as follows

```
2024-01-11T09:42:45.725Z [jfmd ] [INFO ] [                ] [database_bearer.go:403        ] [main                ] [] - Slow statement detected (5.084826495s) - UPDATE md_servers SET last_heartbeat = ? WHERE id = ? [database]
2024-01-11T09:42:45.726Z [jfmd ] [INFO ] [                ] [server_bearer.go:143          ] [main                ] [] - RETRY: fail to update heartbeat for server in the database [ServerInit]
2024-01-11T09:42:55.977Z [jfmd ] [INFO ] [                ] [database_bearer.go:403        ] [main                ] [] - Slow statement detected (5.019563913s) - UPDATE md_tasks SET modified = ?, progress = ? WHERE (task_key = ? AND modified = ? AND progress <> ?) [database] [taskKey][deletedVersionsGarbageCollectorTask] [workerNumber][1]
2024-01-11T09:42:55.977Z [jfmd ] [ERROR] [                ] [async_converter.go:833        ] [main                ] [] - Could not update task progress to Complete, err [database is locked] [async_converter] [taskKey][deletedVersionsGarbageCollectorTask] [workerNumber][1]
2024-01-11T09:43:00.646Z [jfmd ] [INFO ] [                ] [database_bearer.go:403        ] [main                ] [] - Slow statement detected (5.004806014s) - UPDATE md_servers SET last_heartbeat = ? WHERE id = ? [database]
2024-01-11T09:43:00.646Z [jfmd ] [INFO ] [                ] [server_bearer.go:143          ] [main                ] [] - RETRY: fail to update heartbeat for server in the database [ServerInit]
2024-01-11T10:48:15.647Z [jfmd ] [INFO ] [                ] [database_bearer.go:403        ] [main                ] [] - Slow statement detected (5.006373666s) - UPDATE md_servers SET last_heartbeat = ? WHERE id = ? [database]
2024-01-11T10:48:15.647Z [jfmd ] [INFO ] [                ] [server_bearer.go:143          ] [main                ] [] - RETRY: fail to update heartbeat for server in the database [ServerInit]
2024-01-11T13:03:20.646Z [jfmd ] [INFO ] [                ] [database_bearer.go:403        ] [main                ] [] - Slow statement detected (5.004991346s) - UPDATE md_servers SET last_heartbeat = ? WHERE id = ? [database]
2024-01-11T13:03:20.646Z [jfmd ] [INFO ] [                ] [server_bearer.go:143          ] [main                ] [] - RETRY: fail to update heartbeat for server in the database [ServerInit]
2024-01-11T13:03:21.676Z [jfmd ] [WARN ] [                ] [readiness_service.go:53       ] [main                ] [] - Service is unavailable, readiness check failed [readiness]
2024-01-11T13:03:25.656Z [jfmd ] [INFO ] [                ] [database_bearer.go:403        ] [main                ] [] - Slow statement detected (5.006730151s) - UPDATE md_servers SET last_heartbeat = ? WHERE id = ? [database]
2024-01-11T13:03:25.657Z [jfmd ] [INFO ] [                ] [server_bearer.go:143          ] [main                ] [] - RETRY: fail to update heartbeat for server in the database [ServerInit]
2024-01-11T13:05:15.648Z [jfmd ] [INFO ] [                ] [database_bearer.go:403        ] [main                ] [] - Slow statement detected (5.007234096s) - UPDATE md_servers SET last_heartbeat = ? WHERE id = ? [database]
2024-01-11T13:05:15.648Z [jfmd ] [INFO ] [                ] [server_bearer.go:143          ] [main                ] [] - RETRY: fail to update heartbeat for server in the database [ServerInit]
2024-01-11T13:05:25.646Z [jfmd ] [INFO ] [                ] [database_bearer.go:403        ] [main                ] [] - Slow statement detected (5.005158323s) - UPDATE md_servers SET last_heartbeat = ? WHERE id = ? [database]
2024-01-11T13:05:25.646Z [jfmd ] [INFO ] [                ] [server_bearer.go:143          ] [main                ] [] - RETRY: fail to update heartbeat for server in the database [ServerInit]
2024-01-11T13:05:30.655Z [jfmd ] [INFO ] [                ] [database_bearer.go:403        ] [main                ] [] - Slow statement detected (5.0053729s) - UPDATE md_servers SET last_heartbeat = ? WHERE id = ? [database]
2024-01-11T13:05:30.656Z [jfmd ] [INFO ] [                ] [server_bearer.go:143          ] [main                ] [] - RETRY: fail to update heartbeat for server in the database [ServerInit]
2024-01-11T13:05:35.664Z [jfmd ] [INFO ] [                ] [database_bearer.go:403        ] [main                ] [] - Slow statement detected (5.004886732s) - UPDATE md_servers SET last_heartbeat = ? WHERE id = ? [database]
2024-01-11T13:05:35.664Z [jfmd ] [INFO ] [                ] [server_bearer.go:143          ] [main                ] [] - RETRY: fail to update heartbeat for server in the database [ServerInit]
2024-01-11T13:05:36.684Z [jfmd ] [WARN ] [                ] [readiness_service.go:53       ] [main                ] [] - Service is unavailable, readiness check failed [readiness]
2024-01-11T19:17:22.172Z [jfmd ] [INFO ] [                ] [database_bearer.go:403        ] [main                ] [] - Slow statement detected (5.004960549s) - UPDATE md_tasks SET modified = ?, task_start_key = ?, task_end_key = ? WHERE (task_key = ? AND modified = ?) [database] [taskKey][deleteOrphanVersionMigrationTask] [workerNumber][1]
2024-01-11T19:17:22.173Z [jfmd ] [ERROR] [                ] [async_converter.go:428        ] [main                ] [] - Could not update recurrent task, err [database is locked] [async_converter] [taskKey][deleteOrphanVersionMigrationTask] [workerNumber][1]
2024-01-11T19:18:15.645Z [jfmd ] [INFO ] [                ] [database_bearer.go:403        ] [main                ] [] - Slow statement detected (5.004721326s) - UPDATE md_servers SET last_heartbeat = ? WHERE id = ? [database]
2024-01-11T19:18:15.645Z [jfmd ] [INFO ] [                ] [server_bearer.go:143          ] [main                ] [] - RETRY: fail to update heartbeat for server in the database [ServerInit]
2024-01-11T19:18:20.653Z [jfmd ] [INFO ] [                ] [database_bearer.go:403        ] [main                ] [] - Slow statement detected (5.004762185s) - UPDATE md_servers SET last_heartbeat = ? WHERE id = ? [database]
2024-01-11T19:18:20.653Z [jfmd ] [INFO ] [                ] [server_bearer.go:143          ] [main                ] [] - RETRY: fail to update heartbeat for server in the database [ServerInit]
2024-01-11T19:19:50.645Z [jfmd ] [INFO ] [                ] [database_bearer.go:403        ] [main                ] [] - Slow statement detected (5.004803817s) - UPDATE md_servers SET last_heartbeat = ? WHERE id = ? [database]
2024-01-11T19:19:50.645Z [jfmd ] [INFO ] [                ] [server_bearer.go:143          ] [main                ] [] - RETRY: fail to update heartbeat for server in the database [ServerInit]
2024-01-11T19:21:45.645Z [jfmd ] [INFO ] [                ] [database_bearer.go:403        ] [main                ] [] - Slow statement detected (5.004592286s) - UPDATE md_servers SET last_heartbeat = ? WHERE id = ? [database]
2024-01-11T19:21:45.646Z [jfmd ] [INFO ] [                ] [server_bearer.go:143          ] [main                ] [] - RETRY: fail to update heartbeat for server in the database [ServerInit]
2024-01-11T19:21:53.499Z [jfmd ] [INFO ] [                ] [database_bearer.go:403        ] [main                ] [] - Slow statement detected (5.007349019s) - UPDATE md_servers SET last_heartbeat = ? WHERE id = ? [database]
2024-01-11T19:21:53.499Z [jfmd ] [INFO ] [                ] [server_bearer.go:143          ] [main                ] [] - RETRY: fail to update heartbeat for server in the database [ServerInit]
2024-01-11T19:22:45.645Z [jfmd ] [INFO ] [                ] [database_bearer.go:403        ] [main                ] [] - Slow statement detected (5.004346455s) - UPDATE md_servers SET last_heartbeat = ? WHERE id = ? [database]
2024-01-11T19:22:45.645Z [jfmd ] [INFO ] [                ] [server_bearer.go:143          ] [main                ] [] - RETRY: fail to update heartbeat for server in the database [ServerInit]
2024-01-11T19:22:53.904Z [jfmd ] [INFO ] [                ] [database_bearer.go:403        ] [main                ] [] - Slow statement detected (5.005054307s) - UPDATE md_servers SET last_heartbeat = ? WHERE id = ? [database]
2024-01-11T19:22:53.904Z [jfmd ] [INFO ] [                ] [server_bearer.go:143          ] [main                ] [] - RETRY: fail to update heartbeat for server in the database [ServerInit]
2024-01-11T19:26:15.645Z [jfmd ] [INFO ] [                ] [database_bearer.go:403        ] [main                ] [] - Slow statement detected (5.00430295s) - UPDATE md_servers SET last_heartbeat = ? WHERE id = ? [database]
2024-01-11T19:26:15.645Z [jfmd ] [INFO ] [                ] [server_bearer.go:143          ] [main                ] [] - RETRY: fail to update heartbeat for server in the database [ServerInit]
2024-01-11T19:29:20.649Z [jfmd ] [INFO ] [                ] [database_bearer.go:403        ] [main                ] [] - Slow statement detected (5.007322884s) - UPDATE md_servers SET last_heartbeat = ? WHERE id = ? [database]
2024-01-11T19:29:20.649Z [jfmd ] [INFO ] [                ] [server_bearer.go:143          ] [main                ] [] - RETRY: fail to update heartbeat for server in the database [ServerInit]
2024-01-11T19:29:31.169Z [jfmd ] [INFO ] [                ] [database_bearer.go:403        ] [main                ] [] - Slow statement detected (5.007538054s) - UPDATE md_tasks SET modified = ?, progress = ? WHERE (task_key = ? AND modified = ? AND progress <> ?) [database] [taskKey][deletedVersionsGarbageCollectorTask] [workerNumber][1]
2024-01-11T19:29:31.169Z [jfmd ] [ERROR] [                ] [async_converter.go:833        ] [main                ] [] - Could not update task progress to Complete, err [database is locked] [async_converter] [taskKey][deletedVersionsGarbageCollectorTask] [workerNumber][1]
2024-01-12T05:49:02.273Z [jfmd ] [WARN ] [                ] [grpc_utils.go:34              ] [main                ] [] - Refreshing permissions cache invalidation gRPC stream - got an error - error code (Internal) error (rpc error: code = Internal desc = server closed the stream without sending trailers) - resubscribe expected [access_client]
```

By looking at all logs especially access-service and metadata log files, I saw that this issue is happening multiple times a day. Which to me suggest it is not related to when the build happens on our jenkins. Rather it looks like this issue happens every day for few minutes in a day and recovers automatically, it's just we don't see it unless build on jenkins happens at that time, results in failures when accessing artifactory for dependency installation.

Question is there is no special setup involve here as project has very small number of artifacts. To setup artifactory I have only pulled the latest container image so shouldn't everything suppose to work out of box? What are these delete task jobs and where do I even look to fix it?

Comment: Version is OSS 7.46.11 rev 74611900